# Having trouble populating an array in smarty

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, smarty

Im working with a CMS so don't really want to touch the underlying PHP, but theyre using smarty so would like to be able to add some info to a smarty array.

```
    {if $theID[0] == "14"}
        {assign var='myNeededVariables' value=','|explode:"17,49,/monthly,Recurring at \$34.99"}
    {/if}
```

This works but makes the variables as a flat array one level deep.
What I havent been able to do is to push those variables one level deeper, and have the '$theID[0]' value above it. (If that makes sense)

So it would be

```
[14]
     [17]
     [49]
     [/monthly]
     [Recurring at $34.99]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Can you maybe mock up an example of the array that you're trying to create and var dump it for us to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Smarty doesn't provide a lot of functionality to allow you to manipulate data in the template (it's generally considered bad practice, but you probably know that). If I were you, and did not want to alter the CMS code, I would add a custom Smarty function to do most of the work. All you really need to do is create and update arrays, right? So this would be pretty simple:

```php
<?php
function smarty_function_array_accumulate($params, &$smarty)
{
    $assign = null;
    $key    = null;
    $value  = null;
    
    foreach (['assign', 'value'] as $currRequiredParam)
    {
        if (empty($params[$currRequiredParam]))
        {
            trigger_error("array_accumulate: missing '{$params[$currRequiredParam]}' parameter", E_USER_WARNING);
            return;
        }
    }
    
    foreach ($params as $_key => $_val)
    {
        switch ($_key)
        {
            case 'assign':
            case 'key':
            case 'value':
                $$_key = $_val;
        }
    }
    
    $accumulator = $smarty->getTemplateVars($assign) ?? [];
    
    if ($key !== null)
    {
        $accumulator[$key] = $value;
    }
    else
    {
        $accumulator[] = $value;
    }
    
    $smarty->assign($assign, $accumulator);
}
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/rruchte/2548c582d04892cc68e71f4f60a70d2d)

Then in the template, you just call your function with the template var name, the array key, and the value to add:

```smarty
{* Mock $theID array - [14,'foo','bar'] *}
{assign var=theID value=','|explode:"14,foo,bar"}

{* Call our custom array_accumulate function, pass in the first element in theID as the key,
and our needed variables as the value *}
{array_accumulate assign=myNeededVariables key=$theID[0] value=','|explode:"17,49,/monthly,Recurring at \$34.99"}

{* Dump out the result *}
<pre>
{$myNeededVariables|print_r:true}
</pre>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17
            [1] => 49
            [2] => /monthly
            [3] => Recurring at $34.99
        )

)
```

If you do this in a loop, you can obviously build out a larger array.

Comment: oooh, that was quick. Thanks Rob. I'll give this a go>
I appreciate your time